# Storing in Intent in an SQLite database with android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent

I have an android appand I want to store an android Intent in the database as a blob field.  I know the basics of storing and retrieving data of TEXT, INTEGER, etc, standards types in SQLite as my app already does all of that.  I am not familiar with storing and retrieving blobs.  I am presuming the blob is the best way, versus storing as a string and parsing back to and Intent.  Maybe that is not a correct assumption though.  The intents can be a package name, URI, may have extras, etc.  That is why I would like to store/retrieve the whole intent and not just store parts.

Answer (score 10):

You can simply store the intent in a String way:

```
String intentDescription = intent.toUri(0);
//Save the intent string into your database
```

Later you can restore the Intent:

```
String intentDescription = cursor.getString(intentIndex);    
Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(intentDescription, 0);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not store flags and all the extras.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re that isn't true. Please read [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#toUri(int)). "The URI contains the Intent's data as the base URI, with an additional fragment describing the action, categories, type, flags, package, component, and extras."

Comment: Performance of Intent.parseUri() is not very good (it calls String.startsWith too many times).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Parcelable interface with the Intent:

```
Parcel  parcel;  
myIntent.writeToParcel(parcel);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
values.put(MyField, parcel.createByteArray());  
getContentResolver().insert(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Reverse the process to get it out.

If you prefer text, then you could consider using json.

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  From the Android docs [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html):  "Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is *not* appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable."